# Requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs

Tags: java, android, android-studio, cursor

java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{6f31548 13761:com.spotbros.enterprise/u0a88} (pid=13761, uid=10088) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs

and this is the code where i catch the exception:

```
if (scheme.equals("content")) {
        Cursor c = null;
        try {
            c = SpotbrosApplication.getAppContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
            int dataColumnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
            if (dataColumnIndex != -1) {
                // Simplest case: the query returns a column named "_data" with the file real path.
                if (!c.moveToFirst()) {
                    // The cursor returned empty for any reason.
                    return null;
                }
                return c.getString(dataColumnIndex);
            }
            /*
             * The query has not returned the "_data" column, so, as far as we know, the file may well be coming in
             * from Google Drive over Lollipop.
             */
            return copyGDriveFileToFilesFolder(SpotbrosApplication.getAppContext(), uri);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (c != null) {
                c.close();
            }
        }
    }
```